# jsp ArrayList for loop turns only one time

Tags: java, jsp, loops, arraylist

my code is here

```
<% 
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

ArrayList<kisi> arr=(ArrayList<kisi>)request.getSession().getAttribute("arr");
%>

<%for(int i=arr.size()-1;i>=0;i--) { %>
Isim:<strong><%= arr.get(i).name %></strong> <br>
Soyisim:<strong><%=arr.get(i).surname  %></strong><br>
Cinsiyet:<strong><%= arr.get(i).gender%></strong><br>
Sehir:<strong><%= arr.get(i).sehir %></strong><br>
-----------------------------------<br>
<% }%>
```

how ever it loop only one time and show only one  veraible but it have many why?

Comment: Are u sure that variable `arr` contains more than one element? What does `<%= arr.size() %>` show you...

Comment: How do you know it has many values?

Comment: try to print ArrayList size. your code is working fine without any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the block where you have declared the `arr`.

var     `arr`
is local to that block only.
Use declaration tag `<%! declaration %>` for declaring arr. Declaration works for the whole class, while scriptlet declaration work only for their local declaration.

Answer (score 0):

If order is not important you may use this:

for(kisi k : arr) {
   // print data
}

Also, please print the size of the arraylist before the loop starts just to make sure that it has more than 1 record.